Limit tabularray column property to specific rows
Consider a table like the following:
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {ccccl},
  column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
  hline{2-Z} = {2-Y}{},
  vline{2-Y} = {2-Z}{},
}
  & 1 \hfill{} 2 & 3 \hfill{} 4 & 5 \hfill{} 6 &      \\
A & a            & b            & c            & Text \\
\end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}


I would like to reduce the colsep on only the first row, so that each number is placed closer to its nearest column separator.
I have tried specifying something like:
  column{2-Y} = {colsep+=-3pt},

but that affects all rows, not just the first row.
I have also tried:
  vborder{2-X} = {rightspace=3pt},
  vborder{3-Y} = {leftspace=3pt},

but that exhibits the same problem.
When I try limiting column and vborder keys to specific rows, or setting the colsep property on a cell key, I get compilation errors.
Is it possible to achieve a smaller colsep on specific rows using tabularray?
Thanks.
P.S. I'm aware that this can be emulated e.g. by using negative hspace or similar, but I was looking for a perhaps more general/idiomatic/blessed/foreseen approach.

With   leftsep  = 0pt, rightsep = 0pt,  ? But not  for specific rows

@pascal974 AFAICT colsep=<x> is short for and thus equivalent to leftsep=<x>,rightsep=<x>.

Add negative space on either side.
Here I also set a minimum separation of 1em.
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tf}{mm}{%
  \hspace*{-\tabcolsep}#1\hspace{1em plus 1fill}#2\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {ccccl},
  column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
  hline{2-Z} = {2-Y}{},
  vline{2-Y} = {2-Z}{},
}
  & \tf{1}{2} & \tf{3}{4} & \tf{5}{6} &      \\
A & a         & b         & c         & Text \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}


Maybe you don't want the full width; with
\NewDocumentCommand{\tf}{mm}{%
  \hspace*{-0.8\tabcolsep}#1\hspace{1em plus 1fill}#2\hspace*{-0.8\tabcolsep}%
}

you get


Thanks, but I'm trying to space out the numbers horizontally so that each moves closer to the nearest cell edge, not move the numbers closer to the row below them.

@Basil Sorry for the misunderstanding. What do you think of the new version?

Thanks, that's closer to what I was looking for, and is similar to my current workaround, in which I place \hspace*{-0.5\leftsep} and \hspace*{-0.5\rightsep} at the start and end, respectively, of these cells. I'm still holding out for a more general solution in tabularray ;).
